# Generalized Logarithmic Integral

Tags: numerical-methods, analytic-number-theory

Euler's logarithmic integral (of particular application in the Prime Number Theorem, for instance) is of the form
\begin{equation*}
\text{li}(x) := \int_0^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t}
\end{equation*}
and it is well-known that $\text{li}(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$.  There are also useful approximations like the Ramanujan series for $x > 1$:
\begin{equation*}
\text{li}(x) = \gamma + \log_2 x + \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(\log x)^k}{k\cdot k!}
\end{equation*}
Let $\alpha > 0$.  Are there analogues of the above results for
\begin{equation*}
\text{li}_{\alpha}(x) := \int_2^{x} \frac{dt}{(\log t)^{\alpha}}?
\end{equation*}

Comment: Not sure if it is really what you're looking for: Theorem 2.1, pg 48 here: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/.